# I am trying to simple c# program?

Tags: c#, facebook

this is aspx code:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSourceRegistration" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:RegistrationConnectionString %>" OnSelecting="SqlDataSourceRegistration_Selecting" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [UserData]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Where error comes

Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

public partial class Administrator : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

Please help me to resolved?

Comment: And the error is...? (It's very hard to help you resolve a problem when you haven't said what the problem is.)

Comment: CS1061: 'ASP.administrator_aspx' does not contain a definition for 'GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged' and no extension method 'GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged' accepting a first argument of type 'ASP.administrator_aspx' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Then it sounds like the problem isn't in anything you've shown, as you haven't shown anything referring to `GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged`. But it sounds like you've basically said that you want an event handler called `GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged`, but haven't written that method.

Comment: @JonSkeet I suspect vijay just copied the markup and hasn't used a GridView before.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a GridView in your aspx Code. You registered the `GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged` Event to that GridView.
Either you delete that or you add that event to your C# code.

For example:

```
 void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e)  {...}
```